# try and catch error

Tags: java, jdbc, try-catch

```
public class ConnectionManager {
    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prototypeeop";    
    private static String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";   
    private static String usernsme = "root";   
    private static String pasword = "triala";
    private static Connection con;
    private static String url;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // log an exception. fro example:
                System.out.println("Failed to create the database connection."); 
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // log an exception. for example:
            System.out.println("Driver not found."); 
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Hey, I am making this class, and I get a "classnotfound exception is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement"?   This has something to do with my try and catch block, and I am wondering what the problem is.  It says for the try error that, "unreported exception java.lang.classnotfound excpetion must be caught or declared before it is thrown".

I apologize for the obvious questions, but I am new to try and catch blocks too. I know it has something to do with me not declaring this type of error because the SQLException has been declared in the java.sql package; hence, why I don't get an error.  (I include "import java.sql package" in my code since I am using the Connection class for JDBC).  The class basically sets up a connection and returns that connection.

Comment: Copy the exact text from the error -- tell us if it's a compiler or runtime error and tell us the exact line of code it refers to.

Comment: I pasted this code. Aside from syntax errors I don't have any problems with the exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Your text is quite hard to understand... If I understand your issue correctly, this might be the answer:

You must catch SQLException because DriverManager.getConnection declares that it might throw this exception. ClassNotFoundException might be thrown by Class.forName, so you must catch it, too. However, you could use one try block with two catch clauses instead of two.

I guess the best thing would be if you could re-explain the problem.

Comment: [Class.forName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) is supposed to throw a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: He calls Class.forName() which throws ClassNotFoundException. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)

Comment: Tried to clean up the text without modifying it too much, too much modification sometimes hides the findings, or changes the question.

Answer (score 1):

It will throw a ClassNotFoundException exception. Just create a new .java file and see.
I have tried it.Copy the below code into a new java file.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

public class ConnectionManager {
    private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prototypeeop";
    private static String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String usernsme = "root";
    private static String pasword = "triala";
    private static Connection con;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            try {
                con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // log an exception. fro example:
                System.out.println("Failed to create the database connection.");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // log an exception. for example:
            System.out.println("Driver not found.");
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code and now it doe now like my call to the forName method

Comment: i already include the jdbc driver to my project. Should i sitll import the jdbc connection?

Comment: your driver jar is only in the build path.for accessing it inside a class you have to import the jdbc connection.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is directly from your editor, you have this problem to fix

You declare `usernsme` and `pasword`

```
private static String usernsme = "root";
private static String pasword = "triala";
```

but use `username` and `password`

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

perhaps change the first lines to

```
private static String username = "root";
private static String password = "triala";
```

and this problem will go away too.

If this code is not from your editor, then you should probably give us the real code if you want help.